# Upgrade to django 1.7 - instance becomes unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode

I recently moved from django 1.2.5 to 1.7.0 (A long overdue upgrade) and as expected alot of things broke.  I have been able to fix alot of things however I am having one major issue.

I have pickled objects stored in the database. In django 1.2.5, I ran the below commands and below are the results

```
>>> from app.foo.models import MyModel as s
>>> s.objects.get(id = 34567)
<MyModel: Foo (bar)>
>>> x = s.objects.get(id = 34567)
>>> x.myObject
<foor.bar.My Class instance at 0x3855878>
>>> y = x.myObject 
>>> type(y)
<type 'instance'>
```

However on django 1.7.0 I get the below

```
>>> from app.foo.models import MyModel as s
>>> s.objects.get(id = 34567)
<MyModel: Foo (bar)>
>>> x = s.objects.get(id = 34567)
>>> x.myObject
```

> 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'

(This is a snippet of the actual output)

```
>>> y = x.myObject 
>>> type(y)
<type 'unicode'>
```

As such I am not able to access the instance methods. When i check the properties of the object as of 1.7, i get

```
>>> dir(y)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

Here is MyModel:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from SerializedDataField import SerializedDataFiel

class MyModel(models.Model):

    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    code = models.TextField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default = None)

    """Pickled fresh survey object."""
    myObject = SerializedDataField()

    """Can the pickled surveyObj be changed? Once a survey has been activated, myObject cannot be changed"""
    mutable = models.BooleanField(default = None)      

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title + " (" + self.code + ")"
```

And here is Serialized Data Field

```
from django.db import models
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except:
    import pickle

import base64

class SerializedDataField(models.TextField):
    """Because Django for some reason feels its needed to repeatedly call
    to_python even after it's been converted this does not support strings."""
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None: return 
        if not isinstance(value, basestring): return value
        try:
            value = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(value))
            return value
        except:
            return value

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value *args, **kwargs):
        if value is None: return 
        return base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(value))
```

How can I access my instance methods if I keep getting getting a unicode object?

Comment: Please show us the `MyModel` model.

Comment: I have added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. With the migration, we also re-ordered out apps. The code fails here in Serialized Data Field

```
    try:
        value = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(value))
        return value
    except:
        return value
```

Since we had pickled objects already stored in the database, while trying to unpickle the objects, the decode failed because some dependencies had changed. Since the unpicked object is  as is returned in case of failure, we get the unicode data.

To fix this,  I had to restore the apps I had moved to their original position to ensure the serialized field would find packages it depends on.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So the bare `except:` hiding important things strikes again.

Answer (score 3):

*All* text columns in Django are stored as Unicode data. If your column is really *binary* data, you can now migrate those to a [`BinaryField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) (the field was only added in Django 1.6).

For your existing data, you need to encode back to a binary byte string, you can do so with the [Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) codec; Unicode codepoints U+0000 through to U+00FF map one-on-one to Latin-1 bytes:

```
y = x.surveyObject.encode('latin1')
```

The mistake then, was treating binary data as text; it never was text to begin with.